# SQL update field for every value connected with it

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I have to create query, that raises client discount by 10 (adds 10 to previous value) for every order made by this client.

Database structure looks like this:

```
CLIENT(client_id, name, discount)
ORDER(id, client_id)
```

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
UPDATE CLIENT c 
SET c.DISCOUNT = c.DISCOUNT + 10 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDER WHERE client_id = c.client_id)
```

In this statement,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDER WHERE client_id = c.client_id
```

returns the number of orders placed by each client

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE CLIENT SET DISCOUNT=10 WHERE client_id in (SELECT client_id from ORDER)

Comment: I have to update discount +10 for EVERY order. E.g. client x made 10 orders, then discount = discount + 10 * number_of_orders_made_by_client_x.

Comment: then you need this:  UPDATE client c SET discount = discount + 10 * (select count(*) from order WHERE client_id = c.client_id)

Answer (score 0):

Sub query will be the best solution for such cases

UPDATE CLIENT
SET CLIENT.DISCOUNT = CLIENT.DISCOUNT + 10 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ORDER WHERE client_id = CLIENT.client_id)